# Pandas' `to_csv` doesn't behave the same way as printing

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Consider the following sequence of operations:

1. Create a data frame with two columns with the following types `int64`, `float64`
2. Create a new frame by converting all columns to `object`
3. Inspect the new data frame
4. Persist the new data frame
5. Expect the second column to get persisted as shown in the 3rd step: i.e. as string, not as float64

Illustrated below:

```
# Step 1
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'a': [3, 2, 1, 0], 'b': [1, 500.43, 256.13, 5]})  

# Step 2
df2 = df.astype(object)

# Step 3
df2.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 4 entries, 0 to 3
Data columns (total 2 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------  --------------  ----- 
 0   a       4 non-null      object
 1   b       4 non-null      object
dtypes: object(2)
memory usage: 192.0+ bytes

# NOTE notice how column `b` is rendered
df2
   a       b
0  3       1
1  2  500.43
2  1  256.13
3  0       5

# Step 4
df2.to_csv("/tmp/df2", index=False,  sep="\t")
```

Now let us inspect the generated output:

```
$ cat df2
a   b
3   1.0
2   500.43
1   256.13
0   5.0
```

Notice how column `b` is persisted: the decimal places are still present for round numbers even though the datatype is `object`. Why does this happen? What am I missing here?

I'm using Pandas 1.1.2 with Python 3.7.9.

Comment: Changing the type to object does not change what is actually stored in the dataframe, it just changes how the column is printed.

Comment: Thanks @cs95. How can I convert float64 to string in such a way that zeroes are omitted for round numbers?

Comment: There are methods but they aren't pretty. Are you looking to fix a single column, or multiple?

Comment: Multiple - all `float64` columns in a frame (typically there are 2-3 of these)

Comment: To give you more context: I'm trying to compare with output produced by R. R apparently renders round numbers without decimal places.

Comment: You can convert float cols to string and strip out the trivial decimal place: `df.select_dtypes('float').astype(str).apply(lambda x: x.str.rstrip('.0'))`

Comment: `Changing the type to object does not change what is actually stored in the dataframe`: on a side note: how does one effect a change in what is actually stored?

Comment: @cs95 to be pedantic, it *does* change what is stored in the dataframe. In `df`, you have a column with dtype `numpy.float64`, the primitive buffer being wrapped by pandas consists of an array of 64-bit floating point numbers. When you do `astype(object)`, the underlying buffer is converted to an array of PyObject pointers. These all point to python `float` objects. So the data *does* change.

Comment: "it just changes how the column is printed" I'd expect `to_csv` to mirror this behaviour, but I guess the library authors differ.

Comment: "You can convert float cols to string and strip": @cs95 Would you care to write this as an answer? I'll accept the same.

Comment: Oops:  `"22500.0".rstrip(".0")` => `'225'`. So a slightly tweaked version is needed.

Answer (score 1):

I think, **'object'** is NumPy/pandas dtype and not one of the python data types.
If you run:

```
type(df2.iloc[0,1])
```

before step 4, you will get **'float'** data type even though it's been already changed to **'object'**.

You can use:

```
df.to_csv("df.csv",float_format='%g', index=False, sep="\t")
```

instead of casting in step 2.

Comment: `dtype='str'`: Column `b` is used for calculations and should stay as `float`. I only need to change the data type for persisting to a file.

Comment: You can use `df.to_csv("df.csv",float_format='%g', index=False, sep="\t")` to write into the .csv file

Comment: I did consider "%g". However this can potentially result in exponential notation under some circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

I am not great with pandas and still learning. I looked at a few solution and thought why not do an apply on the data before we send it to csv file.

Here's what I did to get the values printed as `1` and `5` instead of `1.0` and `5.0`

## values in df are mix of string, float, ints

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'a': [3, 2, 1, 's', 't'], 'b': [1, 500.43, 256.13, 5, 'txt']})  
df2 = df.astype(object)
def convert(x):
    a = []
    for i in x.to_list():
        a.append(coerce(i))
    return pd.Series(a)
        
    #return pd.Series([str(int(i)) if int(i) == i else i for i in x.to_list()])

def coerce(y):
    try:
        p = float(y)
        q = int(y)
        if p != q:
            return str(p)
        else:
            return str(q)
    except:
        return str(y)

df2.apply(convert).to_csv("abc.txt", index=False, sep="\t")
```

Output in the file will be:

```
a   b
3   1
2   500.43
1   256.13
s   5
t   txt
```

## all values in df are numeric (integers or floats)

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'a': [3, 2, 1, 0], 'b': [1, 500.43, 256.13, 5]})  
df2 = df.astype(object)
def convert(x):
    return pd.Series([str(int(i)) if int(i) == i else i for i in x.to_list()])
df2.apply(convert).to_csv("abc.txt", index=False, sep="\t")
```

The output is as follows:

```
a   b
3   1
2   500.43
1   256.13
0   5
```

Here I am assuming all values in df2 are numeric. If it has a string value, then int(i) will fail.